# How to use curl command via python

Tags: python, curl

I want to send a json file to keen.io in their documentation they use the following command

```
curl "https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/events/EVENT_COLLECTION?api_key=WRITE_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @purchase1.json
```

I am thinking how can I use this to work with python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: Do you want to do this use a Python module? or just  run a GNU program like `curl` use Python?

Comment: I tried using sub process I get an error message  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: It means that `curl` didn't found the file(your json file). Try use the full path like `/home/user/foobar/purchase1.json`

Comment: And you also can try `os.system()` function in `os` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use subprocess module to run the curl command using subprocess.call() method.

eg :

```
 subprocess.call('curl "https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/events/EVENT_COLLECTION?api_key=WRITE_KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @purchase1.json', shell=true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `requests` library to achieve this.

```
import requests
uri = "https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/{}/events/{}?api_key={}".format(PROJECT_ID, EVENT_COLLECTION, API_KEY)
json_payload = open('purchase1.json', 'rb').read()
requests.post(uri, json=json_payload)
```

You can read through their [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for more information.

Comment: First, I don't think that json file needs open in binary mode. Second, I recommend use `with` open the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use subprocess to execute the command and then catch the output https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html